# height of html input element differs, is computed wrong

Tags: html, css, input, firebug

I have a problem with the style of an input element.
The computed tab of firebug displays the height of the field as 16px though the css value of the height is 18px. As you can see in the screenshot, the input area should be as tall as the button on the right.

Screenshot:

[image]

The site is mainly a static html recreation of a dynamically generated site. Though I recreated the whole structure with the corresponding clases, names and ids.

The value 16px is never set, I guess it's the browser default, but why is the value 18px ignored?

Comment: If no mistake, 16px is the inner height. 18px is the total height including 2*1px border.

Comment: please post your code here on jsfiddle.net

Comment: @HugoGiraudel in the dynamically part of the site the 18px are used and then there are added 2*1px borders so that it sums up to 20px, which is as high as the button on the right, correct: http://i.imgur.com/GogbEHn.png

Comment: In the styles tabs of firebug at both situations seen on the screenshots, the last applied css classes are the same, so also the last applied styles are border-widths:1px and heights:18px in both cases. Just in one case the computed height value is 16px

Comment: The doctype was missing in the static rebuild of the site.

Answer (score 2):

The doctype element `<!DOCTYPE html .. etc.` was missing in the static rebuild of the site.
That was why the height was computed wrong.